# TRANSIMS interaction with OSGEO tools

Tags: modelling, transportation

Wow I've just discovered the world of [TRANSIMS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/transims/?source=dlp), a transport model with ambitious aims: "to model all aspects of human behaviour related to
transport in one consistent simulation framework" (Nagel, 1999). I was sceptical at this claim at first, but further [exploration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transims) has revealed that it is increasingly being adopted by Municipal Planning Organisations in the US, is completely [open source](http://code.google.com/p/transims/) (complete with a NASA license), and works on [Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/transims/files/software/4.0.08/transims-4.0.110104.tar.gz/download) as well as Windows.

All this is very exciting for someone researching modelling travel flows.

My question to the GIS community is has anyone got this to integrate with other OSGEO tools such as QGIS, PostGIS or PGrouter (although TRANSIMS has its own route planner)?

There is also a python-based visualiser for this software: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/transimsstudio/?source=recommended

Hope this set of links is of use to others, and hope that people who've encountered TRANSIM can provide insight into its integration with GIS.

Nagel, K., Beckman, R. J., & Barrett, C. L. (1999). TRANSIMS for urban planning. 6th International Conference on Computers in Urban Planning and Urban Management, Venice, Italy. (Available on arXiv).

Comment: Since you're looking at transims, have you looked at urbansim.org ?

Comment: Any updates on your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a preliminary answer based on further research of and experience with agent-based transport models: **use MATSim instead.**

MATSim has a number of advantages over TRANSIM ([Balmer et al. 2009](https://svn.vsp.tu-berlin.de/repos/public-svn/publications/vspwp/2008/08-03/3aug08.pdf)), and has an inbuilt ability to interact with QGIS ([MATSim Tutorial 2.1.4. Installing QGis](http://matsim.org/docs/tutorials/8lessons/installation/software)).

I'm in the process of testing this software (so this answer may need to be updated), but preliminary results suggest that this answers my question [to the T](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061017055732AAyn3t5).

Comment: A short note: Nagel, that you quote on the 1999 paper, is also the main driving force behind MATSim. He started the work on MATSim after returning from the US to Europe, where he could not continue to work on TRANSIMS due to licensing reasons at that time.